# Cocoa Bindings?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa-bindings, sample

Really struggling with creating a simple Cocoa Bindings app. Using Xcode 7.3 - Objective-C. Trying ultimately to get one array to load into a NSTable headings. These will be dynamic, i.e. I don't know before hand how many headings there will be. I'm loading a .csv file for these headings along with associated array values into each appropriate columns. I have these data structures parsed and placed into arrays.

My dilemma is the examples, books and documents I have found and bought are for older versions of Xcode. The bindings section is Xcode has been changed. To simplify and to help my understanding, I was looking for steps (or a demo project) to have one created NSArray with only a few strings load into one NSTableView, either in the heading or in one row.

Thank you.

Comment: would this help? https://www.raywenderlich.com/118835/os-x-nstableview-tutorial

Comment: @robinkunde - Yes, it does, sort of, thank you. I've also been looking at [this one too].(https://www.raywenderlich.com/124490/cocoa-bindings-os-x-tutorial) Both written in Swift. I've managed to get something basic to show one row now, can't seem to figure out how to get a second and third row to show up. I'm having the same issue with the page I linked too.

Comment: Still not getting things to work. And Xcode misbehaves often, at least it does for me with bindings.I was hoping someone would look at this simple project for me and indicate what the heck I'm doing wrong. https://www.dropbox.com/s/pipr9ittnz7giey/Cocoa%20Bindings%20V12.zip?dl=0